# $index is not changing after reorder

Tags: jquery, angularjs

angular ui-sortable for table Row with change in $index.

```
<table>
  <tbody ui:sortable ng:model="product">
   <tr ng-repeat="data in product">
      <td>{{$index}}</td>
      <td>{{data.name}}</td>
   </td> 
  </tbody>
</tbody>
```

js file:

```
 $scope.product=[{name:'tomato'},{name:'tomato1'},{name:'tomato2'},{name:'tomato3'}];
```

Comment: ui:sortable just change DOM, it will not effect to your array. what you want to do?

Comment: is it possible with given DOM..whole row should move and $index should change.

Comment: It does rearrange the model and in [my plunker with code copied from above](http://plnkr.co/edit/KvnKcVR6slG42ZIHuJ1D?p=preview) it also changes the $index for the rows when the model is updated. Do you get any errors in the browser developer toolbar console?

Comment: yeah it's working. i am not using sortable.js and not injecting the 'ui:sortable'   then also it's sortable but $index wasn't changed...